# How to get the sum of multiplied array keys from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

A `cargo` has many `orders`. An `order` has a `quantity` and a `price`. For every `order` in a `cargo`, I want to return the sum of `quantity * price` as a single value.

A `cargo` collection returns data as:

```
{
    "data": {
        "cargo_id": 4,
        "name": "Cargo Name",
        "qty": "366200.00",
        "cost": 140,
        "product_id": 1,
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sample Product"
        },
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "cargo_id": 4,
                "qty": 14200,
                "price": "500"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "cargo_id": 4,
                "qty": 12000,
                "price": "500"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "cargo_id": 4,
                "qty": 5600,
                "price": "500"
            }
        ],
        "comments": "sample",
    }
}
```

I have tried using an Eloquent Accessor in the `Cargo` class as:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cargo extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $appends = [
        'product_margin'
    ];

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function getProductMarginAttribute() {
        $orders = $this->orders();
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $total += $order['qty'] * $order['price'];
        }

        return $total;
    }
}
```

But `product_margin` returns `0`. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  `$this->orders()` return hasmany relationship data. To get the item collection from relationship data you should use `get()`. Update the code in your `Cargo` modal.

```
    public function getProductMarginAttribute() {
        $orders = $this->orders()->get();
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $total += $order['qty'] * $order['price'];
        }

        return $total;
    }
```